# Why is 0 the output for this greatest common divisor recersive method

Tags: java, tail-recursion

I am trying to understands why I keep getting zero when I input my code. Shouldn't b be the last remainder, and thus the greatest common divisor?

```
import java.util.*;
public class GreatestCommonDivisor
{
    public static void input(){
       
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter Guesses");
        
         int a = input.nextInt();
         int b = input.nextInt();
         gcd(a, b, 1, a%b);
    }
    
    public static int gcd(int a, int b, int i, int R){
    if (R == 0){
        System.out.println(b); return R;
    }
    else{
        R = a%b;
        a = b*i + R;
        a = b;
        b = R;
        i++;
        return gcd(a, b, i, R);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning `R` and not `b` in this code? `if (R == 0){ ... return R;}`

Comment: Don't know what algorithm that is supposed to be, but it seems overly complex, given that it can be implemented as simple as `public static int gcd(int a, int b) { return (b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b)); }`